# what in the world is this fungus like plant growing in my wood-chips?

Tags: identification, fungus

This started growing on my wood-chip pile. At first I thoght someone spilt something. But it is sprouting up all over it now.

does anyone know what it is?[image]

[image: fungus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it's a slime mold of some sort. There are tons of different kinds. Search for pictures on the internet, there are lots.

Comment: @pnuts Fuligo septica  look similar but. the color always seem to bright.

Comment: @Br0therBrigham, in my yard it changes color day by day. Bright *fluorescent* yellow when it first appears, later on becoming pinkish beige (digested kibble color)